# setOnFailureExpression not working for #root and #exception

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

```
@Bean
public ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice after() {
    logger.debug("Evaluating expression advice. ");
    ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setTrapException(true);
    advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("#root");
    advice.setSuccessChannel(rtwSourceDeletionChannel());
    advice.setFailureChannel(rtwFtpFailureHandleChannel());
    advice.setPropagateEvaluationFailures(true);
    return advice;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow rtwFtpFailureHandlerFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows
                .from(rtwFtpFailureHandleChannel())
                .handle( msg -> {
                    // code to delete all files except source. 
                    logger.debug("Handling Failure......");

                    List<String> transitPaths = (List<String>) msg.getHeaders().get(AdviceHandlerMessageHeaders.TRANSIT_PATHS); 
                    String sourcePath = (String) msg.getHeaders().get(AdviceHandlerMessageHeaders.SOURCE); 

                    System.out.println("payload: " + msg.getPayload());
                    })
                .get();
}
```

Produces same result for #root and #exception as below:

```
payload: org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice$MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException: Handler Failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [rtwFtpOutboundHandler]; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Failed to execute on session; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.util.PoolItemNotAvailableException: Failed to obtain pooled item, failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=sample.pdf, headers={file_name=sample.pdf, TRANSIT_PATHS=[\\localhost\atala-capture-upload, sample.tif], SOURCE=\\localhost\atala-capture-upload, file_originalFile=\\localhost\atala-capture-upload\sample.tif, id=746728a4-9b9e-847f-6c2c-29aa8a4a5fd6, file_relativePath=sample.tif, timestamp=1549922458296}], failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=sample.pdf, headers={file_name=sample.pdf, TRANSIT_PATHS=[\\localhost\atala-capture-upload, sample.tif], SOURCE=\\localhost\atala-capture-upload, file_originalFile=\\localhost\atala-capture-upload\sample.tif, id=746728a4-9b9e-847f-6c2c-29aa8a4a5fd6, file_relativePath=sample.tif, timestamp=1549922458296}]
```

Answer (score 2):

That works as expected.

The logic is like this:

```
try {
        evalResult = this.onFailureExpression.getValue(prepareEvaluationContextToUse(exception), message);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        evalResult = e;
        logger.error("Failure expression evaluation failed for " + message + ": " + e.getMessage());
    }
    DestinationResolver<MessageChannel> channelResolver = getChannelResolver();
    if (this.failureChannel == null && this.failureChannelName != null && channelResolver != null) {
        this.failureChannel = channelResolver.resolveDestination(this.failureChannelName);
    }
    if (evalResult != null && this.failureChannel != null) {
        MessagingException messagingException =
                new MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException(message, "Handler Failed",
                        unwrapThrowableIfNecessary(exception), evalResult);
        ErrorMessage errorMessage = new ErrorMessage(messagingException);
        this.messagingTemplate.send(this.failureChannel, errorMessage);
    }
```

The evaluation result of the `onFailureExpression` is added to the `MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException` as property. And this exception is wrapped to the `ErrorMessage` to be sent to the configured `failureChannel`.

So, your code is correct so far, unless you are missing the fact that `payload` of the message you process in that `rtwFtpFailureHandlerFlow` is exactly the mentioned `MessageHandlingExpressionEvaluatingAdviceException`. To get access to the result of your expression, you need to cast a `payload` to this exception and call its `getEvaluationResult()`. On the other hand you even don't need to have have any complex expression since a request message is available as a `failedMessage` of this exception. Plus the real failure is in the cause of this exception.

See docs for more info: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#expression-advice